# In ReactJS, why does calling two useState's set functions in one function mess up synchronization?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In react JS I have the following app:

```
function App() {

    const guidance_descriptions = {
        "text":"dummy text A",
        "description": "dummy text B"
    };
    const [guidanceText,setGuidanceText] = useState(guidance_descriptions['text']);

    const ModeButtons = () => {
        const [mode,setMode] = useState("text");
        function changeSelectedMode(e) {
            setMode(e.target.value);
            setGuidanceText(guidance_descriptions[e.target.value]);
        }

        return (
                <div>
                    <input type="radio" value="text" name="selectMode" checked={mode==="text"} onChange={changeSelectedMode}/> Text
                    <input type="radio" value="description" name="selectMode" checked={mode==="description"} onChange={changeSelectedMode}/> Description
                </div>
        )
    }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <ModeButtons/>
      </header>
    </div>
  );

}

export default App;
```

It does not work as intended because I need to click twice to change the radio button to highlight "Description", while only one time to highlight "Text".
However if I remove the `setGuidanceText(guidance_descriptions[e.target.value]);` line above then it works as intended. Why?

Spent 3 hours trying to debug this using various ways such as useEffect. Also watched many videos online but still didn't find the proper explanation or solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In ReactJS, why does calling two useState's set functions in one function mess up synchronization?

It happens because you are breaking the React rules. You shouldn't declare another React component within another React component. You need to click twice to make the "Description" radio button active, because when changing the parent state, `ModeButtons` re-mounts (gets re-declared) with a default value of `mode` that is "text". After another click the `guidanceText` value is not changed anymore, so the parent **does not** re-render, so nor does the child (does not get re-declared anymore) and the value gets toggled correctly.

**Solution**: Move the `ModeButtons` outside the `App` and pass the state values as props.

Comment: That was indeed the issue. Thanks a lot!